# Problems cutting people off

Tags: calls, screen, proximity-sensor

I am a complete novice with these phones.  When I have a call I seem to cut people off with my cheek on the screen - how can I stop this?

Comment: Are you saying that you are accidentally hanging up on people because the screen is touching your face?

Comment: The simple (and stupid) answer is to try holding the phone a little bit further away from your face (as in, make the handset touch your ear but not your cheek) -- however, if this keeps happening it seems more like a problem with the handset, and you should bring it up with the manufacturer.

Comment: This should normally be prevented by the proximity sensor. Either your device doesn't feature one (which would make me wonder), or something is wrong with it. What device do you have, and what Android version is it running?

Answer (score 1):

If  you cannot keep distance between screen and your skin (cheek) as bigbadonk420 said. Then, in my experience, always speak from your phone with headset connected. There by not having the tension of cutting the call and giving freedom to the hands simultaneously.  Simple isn't it...

Answer (score 1):

One solution you can try is to lock the screen after placing or receiving a call. This way you won't cut the call accidentally by touching the screen.